# No messages from my code is getting displayed. Am I doing this incorrectly?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, formview

I have this markup on formview control. The formview has a control id of scoreGrid:

```
<asp:Label ID="PercentLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PercentCorrect","{0:0.00}%" ) %>'
```

All the values from calculations are stored in PercentLabel control as percentages like 83.33% as an example.

Then On codebhind, on pageLoad() event, I have this:

```
Dim myRow As FormViewRow = scoreGrid.Row
Dim lbscore As Label = DirectCast(myRow.FindControl("PercentLabel"), Label)
If lbscore.Text < "75" Then
    Message.Text = "Your score does not meet minimum requirement"
ElseIf lbscore.Text > "75" Then
    Message.Text = "Congratulations; you have passed the test"
End If
```

Based on user's scores, show that the user either passed the test or not.

I am not getting any errors. However, no message is getting displayed.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing strings with greater than and less than logic when you need to use numeric types to do this comparison, like this:

```
Dim number As Single 

If Single.TryParse(lbscore.Text, number) Then
    ' Do comparison logic
    If number < 75 Then
        Message.Text = "Your score does not meet minimum requirement"
    ElseIf number >= 75 Then
        Message.Text = "Congratulations; you have passed the test"
    End If
Else
    ' Could not convert text from lbscore to a Single
    Message.Text = "Error trying to determine your score!"
End If
```

Comment: Great, glad to hear it. If you feel my answer helped you, then feel free to up-vote it and/or accept the answer.